# Minimize window with NoResize mode on

Tags: wpf, resize, window, minimize

I have a WPF application, where `Window` property `ResizeMode` is set on `NoResize`. Hence maximize and minimize button is hidden.

Is there a way to add minimize button? Because I don't want to allow user just resize window in order to not deform controls on form. But minimize window is useful function.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Set `ResizeMode="CanMinimize"`. This avoids window resizing and enables minimize button.